# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items' ....... A type error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to merge two dictionaries. One of them is empty. I have a code in Python 2.x. But I am converting the code in 3.7. I did had convert it. But I don't know if I am doing it right or wrong. As I am totally a newbie. 
The code is actually a video captioning model. Below is the code snippet. Please help me clarify it if I am doing it right.

I have converted the code in 3.7. But I am not sure if I am doing right or not.

```
class DataProvision:
    def __init__(self, options):
        assert options['batch_size'] == 1
        self._options = options
        self._splits = {'train':'train', 'val':'val_1'}

        np.random.seed(options['random_seed'])
        random.seed(options['random_seed'])

        self._ids = {}  # video ids
        captions = {}
        self._sizes = {}
        print('Loading paragraph data ...')
        for split in self._splits:
            tmp_ids = 
             open(os.path.join(self._options['caption_data_root'], split, 
              'ids.txt'), 'r').readlines()
            tmp_ids = [id.strip() for id in tmp_ids]
            self._ids[split] = tmp_ids
            self._sizes[split] = len(self._ids[split])

            tmp_captions = 
         json.load(open(os.path.join(self._options['caption_data_root'], 
           split, 'encoded_sentences.json'), 'r'))
            captions[split] = {tmp_ids[i]:tmp_captions[i] for i in 
            range(len(tmp_ids))}

        # merge two caption dictionaries
        self._captions = {}
        for split in self._splits:
            #self._captions = dict(self._captions.items() + 
             #captions[split].items()) #2.x original code line
            self._captions = {**self._captions, **captions[split]}  #3.7
             #convert the above line in 3.7
```

I'll appreciate any help I can get. Is it clearly replicating the original code or not. Because i am getting error in further code.  Thanks

Comment: In Python-2.x `some_dict.items()` returned a list of 2-tuples, in Python-3.x, it returns a proxy-object.

Comment: The replacement indeed looks correct.

Comment: Thanks, @WillemVanOnsem. 

This is the next part of the code:
`# feature dictionary
        print('Loading c3d features ...')
        features = h5py.File(self._options['feature_data_path'], 'r')
        self._feature_ids = features.keys()
        self._features = {video_id:np.asarray(features[video_id].values()[0]) for video_id in self._feature_ids}`

But now i am getting this error... 
TypeError: 'ValuesViewHDF5' object is not subscriptable

I appreciate a little help here.

Comment: Your title isn't applicable, as you aren't actually trying to add two dictionaries in your code.

Comment: @chepner the title i choose is because thats the error i am getting and yes one is empty dict.